У тебя есть карта банка/Банка СПб/СПБ?
Как правильно?

У тебя есть карта банка/Банка СПб/СПБ


Полное название: Публичное акционерное общество «Банк «Санкт-Петербург».
Сокращенное название: ПАО «Банк «Санкт-Петербург».
Биржевой листинг: BSPB (аббревиатура: Банк "Санк-ПетерБург").
Думаю, что правильно надо писать так:
У тебя есть карта банка "Санкт-Петербург"?
В разговорном варианте допустимо так (можно сказать, при сокращении сокращения):
У тебя есть карта банка СПБ?
В прессе (РИА "Новости"): Канада вводит санкции против банка "Санкт-Петербург"...
Банк России
Банк "Санкт-Петербург"
Дополнение
ПАО "СПБ Банк" — это совершенно другой банк (бывшее ПАО «Бест Эффортс Банк»), зарегистрирован в Москве.

Два банка, говорите? А логотип  БСПБ чей?  На этой же странице: Банк «Санкт-Петербург» подвел итоги развития своей региональной сети в I квартале 2024 года   И вопрос был о сокращенном названии: СПб или СПБ. Как вы обоснуете выбор варианта?   И про количество банков тоже не спрашивали: два или три, без разницы.

@Sharon Вы опять путаете тёплое с  мягким. ПАО «СПБ Банк» — собственность «СБП Биржи». Их логотип латинский — SPB. А ПАО «Банк Санк-Петербург» — бывший «Ленбанк». Их логотип кириллический — БСПБ. Вы внесли ошибочную информацию в свой ответ. Римма справедливо вас поправила, на что имеет полное право.
